# Merge two dataframes based on Time, Latitude and Longitude

Tags: python, dataframe, time

I have two dataframes:

-dfh, that stores daily data with latitude and longitudes (520033 rows × 23 columns):

| id | Latitude | Longitude | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 46.2 | 9.0 | 30/10/2022 |
| 12362 | 45.2 | 10.3 | 29/10/2022 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

-df, that stores daily weather data, with latitude and longitudes (5906264 rows × 15 columns):

| Latitude | Longitude | time | u10 | v10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 35.5 | 6.6 | 30/10/2022 | 1.269 | 1.392 |
| 45.2 | 10.3 | 29/10/2022 | 0.898 | -0.026 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I would need to merge the two dataframes, assigning the daily weather data from df to each latitude-longitude of dfh.

I have tried the following:

```
df_merged = df.merge(dfh, on=['Latitude','Longitude','time'],how='right')
```

But I get a table that where the variables coming from df are always NaN:

| id | Latitude | Longitude | time | u10 | v10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 46.2 | 9.0 | 30/10/2022 | NaN | NaN |
| 12362 | 45.2 | 10.3 | 29/10/2022 | NaN | NaN |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Can anyone understand what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

IMO the problem is with 'right' join where you actually wand either 'left' or 'inner'

Try this:

```
new_df = pd.merge(dfh, df,  how='inner', left_on=['Latitude','Longitude','time'], right_on = ['Latitude','Longitude','time'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've tried your code but I get an empty 0x23 table.

Comment: This is hinting at the root cause of the problem, are the columns in both tables identical (e.g. same type?)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've just realized that the problem is in the Longitude variable. In the df dataframe the variable has the form -> 6.6  6.7  6.8  6.9, while in the dfh it has the form -> 6.400e+00  5.900e+00  5.500e+00  6.700e+00. This is very strange but could stem from the fact that I've used the round function on dfh['Longitude]. Do you know how I could fix this format?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer as mentioned by @Petr Synek. You could round up your longitude,latitude values as follows:

dfh[['longitude','latitude']] = dfh[['longitude','latitude']].round(xxxx)

new_df = pd.merge(dfh, df,  how='right', on=['Latitude','Longitude','time'])

Comment: I have run the following code: dfh['Latitude'] = round(dfh['Latitude'],1)
dfh['Longitude'] = round(dfh['Longitude'],1). Latitude works just fine, but I get that scientific notation in Longitude...Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: It's just the same number actually ie. 6.700e+00 is equivalent to 6.7

Comment: Thank you, I've tried to run the following: new_df = pd.merge(dfh, df,  how='inner', left_on=['Latitude','time'], right_on = ['latitude','time']) that results in a 496440 rows × 25 columns and new_df1 = pd.merge(dfh, df,  how='inner', left_on=['Longitude','time'], right_on = ['longitude','time']) that results in a 47973 rows × 25 columns. I can't understand why the code doesn't work when I consider both variables at the same time (which is my desired output).

Comment: Can you give me an example of what are your desired outputs?